# sdv.tabular module not loading

Tags: python, sdv

Trying to use sdv to create synthetic data. But the `sdv.tabular` module is not loaded into the notebook.

Ran from `sdv.tabular` `import GaussianCopula` trying to import one of the models from the library but I am getting a `'No module named sdv.tabular'` error.

The code I am running is copied from an article that had no issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an updated version, try

```py
from sdv.single_table import GaussianCopulaSynthesizer
```

You can find more about it here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MCTkTj9-93Ei-cLDQoj9AXaqPhpue7a3?usp=sharing#scrollTo=4MSVT6SdGBqY